# How to count record by specific column in SQL SELECT statement and putting that value in another column of that row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to put a count value in the AppNum column for the same student where the FIRST/TOP record in the result set is 1 and the subsequent record would be 2, 3, etc. I attempted to do this using GROUP BY but not getting the result I'm looking for. In the following PIC the FIRST resultset shows what I'm getting and the SECOND resultset is what I'm needing.

Here is a PIC of what I'm looking to do:

[image: Count Question]

The query I've tried to get the correct resultset is below.  Any HELP/DIRECTION would be appreciated:

```
SELECT 
    StudentID, Location, Status, EconomicDisadvantageCode, 
    StatusEffectiveDate, Enddate, SchoolYear, ApplicationTypeCode, 
    LastUpdated, UpdatedAppType, DataSource, COUNT(Status) AS AppNum
FROM 
    #MCS_5
WHERE 
    StudentID IN (SELECT StudentID 
                  FROM #MCS_5 
                  GROUP BY StudentID 
                  HAVING COUNT(StudentID) > 1)
GROUP BY 
    Status, StudentID, Location, Status, EconomicDisadvantageCode, 
    StatusEffectiveDate, Enddate, SchoolYear, ApplicationTypeCode, 
    LastUpdated, UpdatedAppType, DataSource
ORDER BY 
    StudentID ASC, StatusEffectiveDate ASC;
```

Comment: Try adding `ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by StudentID Order by StudentID) as AppNum`

Comment: THANK YOU!! That got it.  Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number` function, its quite handy in this scenario.

```
SELECT StudentID
    ,Location
    ,STATUS
    ,EconomicDisadvantageCode
    ,StatusEffectiveDate
    ,Enddate
    ,SchoolYear
    ,ApplicationTypeCode
    ,LastUpdated
    ,UpdatedAppType
    ,DataSource
    ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Studentid,STATUS ORDER BY [STATUS]) 
     Appnum
FROM #MCS_5
WHERE StudentID IN (
        SELECT StudentID
        FROM #MCS_5
        GROUP BY StudentID
        HAVING COUNT(StudentID) > 1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use window functions for everything:

```
Select ...
From (select t.*,
             Row_number() over (partition by studentid order by status) as seqnum,
             Count(*) over (partition by studentid) as cnt
      From #mcd_5 t
     ) t
Where cnt > 1
```